# No me encuentra imagen para usar de fondo

Tags: html, css

Me encontraba haciendo mi pagina web cuando tuve un problema al momento de agregar una imagen para usar de fondo pero parece que mi html no la encuentra. Actualmente tengo escrito esto en la etiqueta  arriba de todo el resto de la pagina

```
<style> 
    BODY{
                        background-color: rgb(231, 171, 206);
                        background-image: url('../static/images/fondo.png');
                        background-size: cover;
                    }
</style>
```

creo que el problema es al momento de la url. Para mas explicacion: Creo que como estoy haciendo el css dentro del html propio el css toma la direccion del html y por eso vuelvo para atras para luego seguir por la carpeta "static".

Entonces porque podria ser que el html no encuentra la imagen? puede ser que tiene de inicio el desktop y no la carpeta donde se ubica el html?

Comment: Usa referencias absolutas y no tendrás ese problema en ninguna página donde pongas ese CSS esté en la ruta que esté el html situado. Las rutas absolutas parten de la raíz del dominio y empiezan por una barra, por ejemplo: `/imagenes/static/images/fondo.png`.

Comment: Buenos dias intente usar una referencia absoluta y no funciono... puede ser problema del navegador?

Comment: No creo. A ver, intenta abrir la imagen directamente con el navegador, es decir, pon esto en la url de tu navegador `http://midominio.com/imagenes/static/images/fondo.jpg`  (adaptado a  tu dominio y ruta correcta, claro).  Cuando consigas verlo allí entonces le quitas el `http://dominio.com` y lo pones en el background-image a ver si te funciona.  Si no te funciona entonces ponlo entero, con el `http://dominio.com` incluido y debería funcionar.

Comment: Hola muchas gracias por la respuesta. Nunca pude agregar la imagen de manera local ya que despues tuve el problema de que los navegadores no permiten usar archivos locales. Al final termine subiendo la imagen a una pagina para poder usarla. Aun asi agradezco toda la informacion que me has dado y he corregido aquellos errores.

Answer (score 1):

Te diré las posibles soluciones a tu problema:

> Trata de no llamar a tus clases en mayúsculas ya que no es muy recomendable, puede que tengas posibles errores en tus futuros proyectos. Llámalo tal cual está en el nombre de la etiqueta:

```
body{
  background-color: rgb(231, 171, 206);
  background-image: url('../static/images/fondo.png');
  background-size: cover;
}
```

> También asegúrate de entrar correctamente a la ruta de las carpetas, Por ejemplo: Los caracteres `./` busca un archivo o carpeta dentro de la carpeta en el que está tu css o html. En el caso que sea `../`, te redirecciona a la carpeta anterior y busca las carpetas o archivos que pongas luego del `/`.

```
background-image: url('../static/images/fondo.png');
```

> Si quieres usar una imagen de internet, pon la dirección URL completa:

```
background-image: url(https://imgur.com/wBWzOZo);
```

Si quieres más información del llamado de rutas, te invito a que leas la [documentación](https://uniwebsidad.com/libros/referencia-css2/background-image).

Comment: Hola muchas gracias por la respuesta. Nunca pude agregar la imagen de manera local ya que despues tuve el problema de que los navegadores no permiten usar archivos locales. Al final termine subiendo la imagen a una pagina para poder usarla. Aun asi agradezco toda la informacion que me has dado y he corregido aquellos errores.

Answer (score 1):

Lo estás haciendo parcialmente bien, de hecho el problema es que no nos muestras tus rutas.

Visualmente no es bueno usar mayúsculas, aunque de todas formas, al usar `BODY` te está leyendo el estilo.

Prueba de esta forma:

```
<style> 
    body{
        background-color: rgb(231, 171, 206);
        background-image: url('static/images/fondo.png');
        background-size: cover;
    }
</style>
```

Suponiendo que el archivo HTML donde tienes los estilos, se encuentra de esta manera (junto a la carpeta static):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola muchas gracias por la respuesta. Nunca pude agregar la imagen de manera local ya que despues tuve el problema de que los navegadores no permiten usar archivos locales. Al final termine subiendo la imagen a una pagina para poder usarla. Aun asi agradezco toda la informacion que me has dado y he corregido aquellos errores.