# HTML no linkea con imágenes ni css

Tags: html, css

En forma local puedo ver mi css e imágenes perfectamente; cuando subo mi página al host se muestra el html perfecto pero no me está linkeando styles.css, ni las imágenes, ni nada. Sé que es algún problema de nombre de directorio porque en forma local funciona pero no cuando lo subo a public-html.

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Titillium+Web:wght@400;600;700;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="icon" href="img/mdlogoico.ico">
    <title>MD Broker</title>
</head>
```

---

Adjunto la captura del public-html en el hosting y lo que está adentro de la carpeta css (está nombrado igual que en el archivo)[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Probé estas y ninguna funciona

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/public_html/css/styles.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.marcelodeve.com.ar/css/styles.css">
```

Esto es lo que me dice el directorio cuando abro el css en el host

```
/home2/marcelodevecom/public_html/css/styles.css
```

Comment: Hola @Juani, sería bueno que adjuntaras una imagen de como están las carpetas de tu host. Así podemos validar si es un problema de rutas

Comment: Intenta directamente con la ruta absoluta `/public_html/TuPagina/css` porque yo tambien uso host y me funciona bien la ruta, es extraño que no lo tome, tambien considera las reglas del host que tienes.

Comment: Por favor leer [ask] y realizar el [tour]. [es.so] no es una red antisocial que funciona como hilos de temas. El formato es simple: **1** pregunta y una o más respuestas. El espacio de la pregunta es sólo para la pregunta y el espacio de las respuestas es sólo para respuestas. No crees publicaciones en el área de respuesta cuando no son respuestas a la pregunta original. Saludos

Comment: Voy a escribir una respuesta con lo que creo que ocurre para no llenar la sección de comentarios, aunque no estoy seguro de que luego resulta una respuesta correcta

Comment: Creo que esta es tu página web: http://www.marcelodeve.com.ar/index.php. Que sepas que a mí me carga todo perfectamente.

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza los ../ en tu ruta relativa.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/styles.css">
```

Tal vez te ayude.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que hacer bien el llamado de directorios, utilizando el `./` o `../`. En [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/543301/no-me-encuentra-imagen-para-usar-de-fondo/543440#543440) que es algo similar a tu caso, he echo una respuesta que te puede ayudar.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/styles.css">
```

Answer (score 0):

Observando la imagen, **leo que la mayoría de archivos son de hace 5 años, excepto unos pocos que son de hace unas horas porque, imagino, han sido modificados.**

Puede ser que te hayas puesto a trabajar sobre el código de otro y, entonces, has tocado algo que no debías. De hecho, las modificaciones se han producido precisamente en las carpetas de imágenes y de CSS, además de en el formulario de contacto.

Cuando corremos **en local, a no ser que usemos un servidor de prueba como Xampp, el código PHP no se tiene en cuenta** (dicho bruscamente). Así, es muy probable que el fallo esté en el formulario de contacto y no en las carpetas de imágenes y CSS, pues estas en local sí se ejecutan y, según dices, funcionan bien.

Ahora que ya tenemos por dónde empezar, revisa a fondo ese formulario de contacto. Se me ocurre que un **fallo en contactform.php** esté provocando una parada en la carga de archivos, es decir, un error fatal que impide cargar más hasta que sea corregido.

Pero, ¿cómo sucede dicho fallo? Te pongo un ejemplo práctico. He descargado una página al azar de internet y esto es lo primero que leemos en la página principal:

```
<?php

include 'config.php';
```

Las primeras dos líneas de código son de PHP. **Estas son las dos primeras líneas que se van a leer**. Un error fatal en config.php podría provocar que el resto del código no se ejecutara, es decir, no se importarían los archivos CSS, JS, imágenes...

Es solo una teoría, pues las rutas están bien. Hay quienes te dicen que uses "./ruta" o "../ruta", pero no es necesario en tu caso. El primero, "./ruta", se usa cuando la ruta parte del mismo punto que el documento en el que estamos escribiendo dicha ruta. Por ejemplo, "css/styles.css" significa que el archivo styles.css se encuentra dentro de la carpeta css, la cual está en la misma ruta que index.html.

En el caso de "../ruta", es para que busque hacia atrás el punto de partida de la ruta y que avance a partir de ahí.

En tu caso, "css/styles.css" significa lo mismo que "./css/styles.css", pero en una forma coloquial, digamos. Por eso siempre recomiendo ser más formal. En todo caso, puedes encontrar información sobre esto en Internet.

Cualquier cosa, pregunta sin miedo :)

Comment: Y, como dije en los comentarios, esto es solo una teoría de dónde puede estar el fallo. No me crujan si me he columpiado. Lo escribí en una respuesta para no escribir decenas de comentarios