# No se muestran las imágenes de los productos en ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

estoy tratando de mostrar unos productos. Los datos se muestran bien. Tanto el nombre como el precio. El problema viene cuando trato de mostrar las imágenes del producto. Aparecen como enlaces rotos. Enseño el código

Este es el Componente producto.

```
    import { Component } from 'react'
     
    class Producto extends Component {
        render() {
            const producto = this.props.producto
            
            return(
                <div>
                    <img alt={producto.name} src={producto.img} />
                </div>
            )
        }
    }
```

El componente Productos

```
    import { Component } from 'react'
     
    class Productos extends Component {
        render() {

            const { productos, agregarAlCarro } = this.props

            return(
                <div>
                    {productos.map(producto => 
                        <Producto
                            agregarAlCarro={agregarAlCarro}
                            key={producto.name}
                            producto={producto}
                        />
                    )}
                </div>
            )
        }
    }
```

Y finalmente este es el componente App. De aquí salen los datos de los productos

```
import { Component } from 'react'
import Productos from './components/Productos'

class App extends Component {
    
    state = {
        productos: [
            {name: 'Tomate', price: 1.50, img:'images/tomate.jpg'},
            {name: 'Lechuga', price: 1.20, img:'images/lechuga.jpg'}
        ]
    }

    render() {

    const { productos, agregarAlCarro } = this.props

    return(
        <div>
            <Productos
                agregarAlCarro={() => console.log("No hago nada") }
                productos={this.state.productos}
            />
        </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Estos son los tres componentes que tengo en mi aplicación. La estructura de carpetas es esta.

[image: Estructura de carpetas]

Edito:
He probado con una url de una imágen que he sacado de wikipedia y ha funcionado. Pero con las imágenes de la carpeta no funciona.

Comment: puede ser que este mal la ruta de la imagen, te recomiendo que en tu array en el elemento `img` solo pongas el nombre de la imagen y en `src` introduzcas la ruta y luego solo llamas el nombre de la imagen con su respectivo formato.

Comment: y definitivamente es un error de ruta, mira que el archivo `producto.js` esta dentro de la carpeta `components`, tendrías que agregar `../` antes de llamar `producto.img`

Comment: Ya lo he intentado. Pero el problema persiste Lo he hecho de la siguiente manera
src={`../images${producto.img}`}
No sé si será la forma adecuada de hacerlo,. La consola no muestra errores

Comment: intenta hacerlo como te dije, en el elemento `img` de tu array de productos solo introduce el nombre de la imagen con su respectivo formato ejemplo: `imagen.jpg`

Comment: Acabo de probar a poner directamente el nombre de la imagen y nada

Comment: pues ponle la ruta completa desde la raiz de tu proyecto, es decir, `img:'/images/tomate.jpg'` a ver si cuela

Comment: si ya cambiaste tu array y en el elemento img solo pusiste el nombre y el formato de la imgen entonces tenes que llamar a la imgen de esta manera `src="../images/${producto.img}"`

Comment: Ya lo he intentado y nada funciona

Comment: Si la carpeta de tus imágenes están afuera de la carpeta de tu archivo utiliza `../images/`, y si está 2 carpetas anteriores, utiliza `../../images/`, también puedes utilizar la ruta absoluta de tu imagen (la ruta completa desde la raíz del proyecto). En [ésta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/543301/no-me-encuentra-imagen-para-usar-de-fondo/543440#543440) pregunta explico mejor sobre ésto. En [ésta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/546466/html-no-linkea-con-im%c3%a1genes-ni-css/546623#546623) pregunta también.

Comment: Supongo que por tu estructura no la tienes en area `public`. Por lo que tendrías que importarla para poder usarla. intenta con `src={require(producto.img)}`

Comment: He intentado poner la ruta absoluta desde la raíz del proyecto y nada. También he actualizado la pregunta.  Si utilizo la url de una imagen sacada de internet funciona bien

Comment: Lo más probable es que no estes "sirviendo" correctamente las imágenes que quieres mostrar. Si inspeccionas la consola de tu navegador, en la pestaña "network" o "red" deberías ver requests con error, que deberían ser tus imágenes que no estas pudiendo obtener. Podrías confirmar esto?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu codigo no funciona por que tus imagenes estan almacenadas en tu carpeta de desarrollo de react js, por lo que al llamar a "images/tomate.jpg" tu codigo intenta recuperar esta ruta desde la carpeta que contiene tu app.js generado por React en tu carpeta public.

Si deseas recuperar la imagen que esta almacenada en tu carpeta de desarrollo debes importarla en tu archivo, quedando tu codigo de la siguiente manera.

```
import { Component } from 'react'
import Productos from './components/Productos'
import imgTomate from './images/tomate.jpg'
import imgLechuga from './images/lechuga.jpg'

class App extends Component {
    
    state = {
        productos: [
            {name: 'Tomate', price: 1.50, img: imgTomate},
            {name: 'Lechuga', price: 1.20, img: imgLechuga}
        ]
    }

    render() {

    const { productos, agregarAlCarro } = this.props

    return(
        <div>
            <Productos
                agregarAlCarro={() => console.log("No hago nada") }
                productos={this.state.productos}
            />
        </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Espero haberte ayudado, saludos.

Comment: Esta vez sí ha funcionado. Muchas gracias